# Can I see online users in Django using middleware?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am making a website to learn Django and I am trying to make it possible to check who is online right now. I managed to do it using cookies, but I also have a desktop app that connects to the server and you can log in there as well, so users from the app were not shown as online.

I saw a solution using sessions, so I might end up using it, but I have been learning about middleware and I am wondering if it would be possible to add a field to user model (last_activity) that would be updated by middleware everytime user sends a request to the server (so every time they go anywhere on the website). Then I would add a cut off time (5 minutes or something), and display it on a home page. The only issue is I am not good with middleware yet, and chatGPT suggested this:

```py
class ActivityMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = get_user(request)

            user.last_activity = datetime.now()
            user.save()
        return response
```

But it only updates on logging in, do you know how to change it to update on any request?
Thanks!

Trying to make a middleware that would track users activity

Comment: You might be better off using websockets (you can just increase and decrease a counter in a cache), but that may be a bit too advanced. Here's a video which convers analytics, which might be going in the direction you want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpZOVmEw9Qg

Comment: Why don't you want to use sessions? This feature comes for free with sessions.